# Issues faced to run Corda Sample application in Windows Environment

Tags: intellij-idea, corda

I'm facing issues to run few sample demo application in Windows Environment while the same application is being run successfully in MacOS.

Steps followed:

1. Open the application in Intellij IDEA
2. Project Structure: Set the JDK path
3. I'm unable to see "Import Gradle Project" Under Events Log. This option is enabled in MacOS and easy for me to execute the application.

I tried few other methods to import gradle as well, but I'm unable to run the application.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried via command prompt? Just go to the cordapp DIR and do a gradle deployNodes.(make sure you've gradle 4.4.1 or below). Once the Build in done, go inside the build/Node DIR execute bat file named runnodes.